# How to Run Two T-Sql Statement By Exec Command in SqlServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want run 2 SQL queries in Exec instruction, how can I do this?

`ListOfLeaveRemainingInfo` is a user-defined table type:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetLeaveRemainingTempTable]
    (@LeaveRemainingTempTable [dbo].ListOfLeaveRemainingInfo READONLY,
     @TempTableName NVARCHAR(420)
    )
AS
    EXEC('CREATE TABLE ' + @TempTableName + '
                     ( PersonnelId int, 
                     PersonnelNo nvarchar(512), 
                     FirstName nvarchar(512), 
                     LastName nvarchar(512), 
                     WorkSectionTitle nvarchar(512), 
                     StaffTitle nvarchar(512)
                     );

INSERT INTO ' +@TempTableName + ' 

SELECT * FROM  @LeaveRemainingTempTable 
'
)
```

When I run the stored procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 33
>   Must declare the table variable "@LeaveRemainingTempTable"

Comment: In this case, you could just use `select into` and do it all in one statement.

Comment: Variables declared in an outer scope are not available to a dynamic batch. You'd have to pass it as a parameter again, using `sp_executesql`. That said, this looks like the kind of "too clever by half" solution that's, well, too clever by half. Consider `INSERT ... EXEC` in the outer scope rather than making the sproc responsible for a dynamic table. If this is an attempt to share data between stored procedures, consider also reading [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).

Comment: If Possible Post an answer , How can I do This?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scratch the previous.

@LeaveRemainingTempTable is a table variable. It therefore doesn't exist within the scope of the dynamic SQL.

If dbo.listofleaveremaininginfo always has the same columns you can pass it in as a table variable:-

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetLeaveRemainingTempTable]
(
@LeaveRemainingTempTable     [dbo].ListOfLeaveRemainingInfo     READONLY,
@TempTableName NVARCHAR(512)
)
AS

Declare @mysql varchar(max), @params varchar(255)

Set @mysql='CREATE TABLE ' + @TempTableName + '
                     ( PersonnelId int, 
                     PersonnelNo nvarchar(512), 
                     FirstName nvarchar(512), 
                     LastName nvarchar(512), 
                     WorkSectionTitle nvarchar(512), 
                     StaffTitle nvarchar(512)
                     );

INSERT INTO ' +@TempTableName + ' 

SELECT * FROM  @LeaveRemainingTempTable_IN'

if exists (select * from sys.types where name = 'LeaveReaminingTempTable')
    drop type  LeaveReaminingTempTable

create type LeaveReaminingTempTable as table (id int)

declare @t  LeaveReaminingTempTable
insert @t 
select * from @LeaveRemainingTempTable

exec sp_executesql @mysql, N'@LeaveRemainingTempTable_IN  LeaveReaminingTempTable readonly', @t
```

Comment: Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure prs_Leaves_SetLeaveRemainingTempTable, Line 41 [Batch Start Line 0]
Must declare the scalar variable "@LeaveRemainingTempTable".

Comment: after Your Change

Comment: i thinks it is imposible !

Comment: updated - I spotted that you are using a table variable

Comment: The If exists / drop type is just a check to make sure that the Type doesn't already exist. If it does then the Create Type will error.